# Plotting logarthmic chart - N log N in Excel

Tags: excel, plot, charts, excel-charts, trendline

I am currently analysing and profiling Quick Sort with numerous data size. I have already collected the required data from the profiler. And I have also plotted the graph for the average run time against the data size.

Now I would like to plot the N log N chart as well so that I can compare the theoritical data against the data I have. However I am not able to plot the N log N graph using excel.

There is an option under Chart Design --> Add Chart Element --> Trendline --> Logarithmic. It also gives us the option to customise it as shown below.

[image]

However I am not entirely sure about plotting N log N using this feature. I need this for analysing the Quick Sort and few other sort algorithms.

Comment: I did that, but I wouldn't be able to compare two graphs visually. What I am trying to say here is for Insertion sort its O(nˆ2). So after plotting the graph with the recorded data, I then to trendline and selected Polynomial of order 2 and checked on "Display R-squared value on chart". The R value was close to 1, somewhere around 0.9987 which proved that my analysis of Insertion Sort is good.
I thought of doing something similar here as well with Quick Sort.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm still looking to do this in 2021.... Did you get a fix?

Answer (score -1):

You have `time`(y-axis) and `n`(x-axis) and as you already did, you can plot a graph and get the trendline easily by using some options in Chart dialogue.

More importantly, you can also get the trendline equation by `linest()` (for linear regression). You should search and learn [how to use linest()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) for sure. In short, what you have to do now is just to add another column and fill it `n * log` and then use `linest()` with those columns.

[image]

The image is a portion of what I have done many years ago. `B3:B11` is `n` and `L3:L11` is `time` for randomized input data. As you can see, you can say that for randomized input, quicksort's performance is the most well fitted to `n*log(n)` because its `R^2` (`L21`, which you should look carefully its forumula) is very close to `1.0` and the largest among `n` and `n^2`. Likewise, for already sorted(`M3:M11`) or reversly sorted(`N3:N11`) input, you can see and say that its performance is almost `n^2`. Hope this will help you.